# Using t-sql MERGE to copy or create data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As my starting point I have data like in tblMyTable:

```
Id   Date
37   01/01/2019
```

Or I may have:

```
Id   Date
37   01/01/2019
38   01/01/2018
39   01/01/2018
```

I'd like to copy the Date from Id=37 to Ids 38 and 39 if Ids 38 and 39 exist.  If Ids 38 and 39 don't exist exist I'd like to insert a record with Id = 38 and Id=39 with the Date from Id=37.

So at the end of the day I'd like to have:

```
Id   Date
37   01/01/2019
38   01/01/2019
39   01/01/2019
```

Whether or not 38 and 39 are in tblMyTable at the beginning.

It seems like in theory I should be able to do this with a MERGE but I can't figure out how the USING clause would work.  Am I just going to have to break this down into two statements?

Thanks,

Comment: Just curious why not use 'union all'?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not clear on how UNION ALL would help.

Comment: First, select the row where id = 37 and union all next two rows. You can get what you expected. I do not understand why it needs to merge in this case.

Comment: I don't see how I can union all if the rows don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
with cte AS (
  select a.id, b.date from (
    select 38 id 
    union all
    select 39
  ) a cross join (
    select date from tblMyTable where Id = 37
  ) b
)

merge into tblMyTable t
using cte c on (t.id = c.id)
when not matched by target then
insert (id, date) values (c.id, c.date)
when matched then
update set date = c.date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c4cd695953f502d996d0d70447b0f2d).